# English thesaurus program for Windows

Tags: windows, offline, language, thesaurus

I'm looking for an English Thesaurus program to use in Windows. While I could just go out a buy one, I think it would be more effective if I had a digital one which I could just swap out to while typing (also would mean more space on my desk).

#### Requirements

- Offline: my development computer does not connect to the internet, that mean neither the program or the installer can connect online.
- Compatible with Windows 7: obviously my OS.
- Not restricted to 32/64-bit: I hate this with iTunes and other installers how even if I get a 32-bit installer, just because my OS is 64-bit I can't even install it and should I upgrade my PC I may not have a 64-bit system.

#### Optional

- Free: while I wouldn't mind paying I would rather it's free, we can get dictionaries for free via Notepad++ so I would assume there would be a free thesaurus program.
- Plugin to Notepad++: since I do alot of my typing in Notepad++ it would be good if the thesaurus was like a plugin for Notepad++ which makes it float around like how the search box does, though I'm not entire fussed.
- Compatible with Window XP: sometimes at work I do work on my laptop which is Windows XP so if I can use this thesaurus on XP as well it'll be great.

Comment: I am using a PDF. Probably not what you are looking for, since its Methaphers, but may it helps you aswell. Advantages: does not need the internet, it is compatible with nearly all OS. It is not restricted to 32/64 bit, not as heavy as a book. It is free.

Disadvantage: Not a plugin ;)

 http://www.e-reading.ws/bookreader.php/135023/Thesaurus_of_Traditional_English_Metaphors_(2nd_Ed).pdf

Comment: alright, there you go (word thesaurus, but still a pdf) http://www.4shared.com/get/AJTiSzOM/oxford_thesaurus_-_an_a-z_dict.html

Comment: You can find a multi-lingual offline thesaurus at [ThesaurusGizmo.com](http://www.thesaurusgizmo.com/) It doesn't require a connection and works on windows with office. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJQX.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJQX.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using [Artha](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Home) now for a couple of years, and it is more than just a standard thesaurus.

It is both a dictionary as it provides the meaning(s) of entered queries, and a thesaurus because it provides synonyms, antonyms, derivatives plus a number of other relationships to your query. Even better, it allows you to follow paths through those relationships by double-clicking any word in the interface and has navigation buttons to delve backwards and forwards through your search history.

It is 100% offline because it bundles the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) database and as such doesn't need to connect to the internet, it is open source and thus is completely free, it supports WindowsXP and up, and is 32-bit so will run fine on both 32- and 64-bit systems.

The only thing it doesn't have that you requested is Notepad++ integration.

For the sake of disclosure: I am the packager of a portable version of Artha, but am in no way affiliated with Artha itself. I don't and can't earn anything from any download of Artha or any derivatives of it.

Answer (score 1):

[WordWeb](http://wordweb.info/free/) is pretty good. It is free, and it runs on both 32 and 64 bit machines, with various versions of Windows (XP/Vista/7/8/10). According to the linked web page, the free version offers:

> - One-click lookup in any almost any Windows program
> - Hundreds of thousands of definitions and synonyms
> - Updated with the latest international English words
> - Works offline, or reference to Wikipedia and web references

[image: WordWeb]
<sup>*WordWeb* (source: [WordWeb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx8mUm.png); click image for larger variant)</sup>

There's also an extended "Pro" version, starting at a price of about 20 Euro; additional dictionaries and word lists can be obtained as well.

This should meet most of your requirements:

- **Offline:** Yes.
- **Compatible with Windows 7:** Yes.
- **Not 32/64bit dependent:** Just a single installer, so this is met too.
- **opt: Free?** Yes, free version is available.
- **opt: XP?** Yes, listed as being compatible.
- **opt: Npp?** Not tested, but they state "almost any Windows program". Probably not a plugin, but should work together.